# ListView.refresh() does not work

Tags: java, listview, javafx, gson

somehow, although stated in the JavaDoc, the method refresh() does not work for me, only by calling setItems() again, which takes a lot of time especially when the associated ObservableList is long, works for me. This is my source code:

NetworkManager class, getStations() method

```
ObservableList<Station> getStations() {
        ObservableList<Station> stations = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        JsonArray jsonArray = getRootElement().getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("stations");
        for(JsonElement currentElement : jsonArray) {
            stations.add(gson.fromJson(currentElement, Station.class));
        }
        return stations;
}
```

Then I build up a connection between the ListView and this method in my JavaFX initialization method:

```
listView.setItems(networkManager.getStations());
```

Now, if I register a new object of Station and I use

```
listView.refresh();
```

the ListView does not get refreshed, only this one works:

```
listView.setItems(networkManager.getStations());
```

What is wrong here?

Kenta1561

EDIT:
My Application-class extending main class:

```
package de.kenta1561.enr.main.java;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class EasyNetworkRegistration extends Application {

private File file;
private Controller controller;

private boolean fileCreated;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    showFileChooser(primaryStage);
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/de/kenta1561/enr/main/resources/EasyNetworkRegistration.fxml"));
    TabPane pane = loader.load();
    controller = loader.getController();
    initializeController();
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("EasyNetworkRegistration");
    primaryStage.show();
    setCenter(primaryStage);
}
```

How I add a station to my JSON file:

```
void addStation(Station station) {
        JsonObject rootObject = getRootElement().getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray jsonArray = rootObject.getAsJsonArray("stations");
        jsonArray.add(gson.toJsonTree(station));
        writeToFile(rootObject);
}
```

PS: Obviously the refresh() method gets called after this method gets called so that should not be the issue, I assume.

Comment: Big help would be to see your application extending class here to see how its done

Comment: How are you adding the new item?

Comment: If I am correct first you adding the station to the JSON then reading it with getStations() ? you will need to update observableList for the listener to know something changed - @James_D already answered +1 from me

Comment: as an aside: never-ever use refresh - even if it might appear to work, there's a very high probability that it hides some issue in your updating code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing your `addStation` method does is update the JSON file. There's no way the table is going to know that anything has changed. The call to `refresh()` merely reloads the data from the same `ObservableList`, which, again, you haven't changed.

Consider adding the new station to the observable list directly:

```
void addStation(Station station) {
        JsonObject rootObject = getRootElement().getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray jsonArray = rootObject.getAsJsonArray("stations");
        jsonArray.add(gson.toJsonTree(station));
        writeToFile(rootObject);
        listView.getItems().add(station);
}
```

(Refactor this in the obvious way if `addStation` is not in your controller.)

There should be no need to call `refresh()`.

Comment: Thank you so much :D Why didn't I think of this approach